# Oracle SQL Query Help finding entries that a column has two possible values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I apologize if this question isn't formatted correctly, I normally don't ask SQL questions. I have the following query created for my oracle database

```
SELECT * FROM X_METER_USE x
LEFT JOIN INSTRUMENTS i on x.ID_NUMBER = i.NAME and x.INST_SNR = 'INSTRUMENT'
LEFT JOIN STANDARD_REAGENT sr ON x.ID_NUMBER = sr.SAMPLE_NUMBER AND x.INST_SNR = 'SNR'
WHERE x.INST_SNR = 'SNR' AND sr.SAMPLE_NUMBER = i.NAME;
```

The high level idea is that entries in this `X_METER_USE` table correspond to a test engineers in my organization have performed in a project. They performed the test with a measuring instrument from the `INSTRUMENT` table or a chemical from the `STANDARD_REAGENT` table. In an `X_METER_USE` entry, if the `INST_SNR` column has the value "INSTRUMENT," they used an instrument to perform the test, if the value is "SNR" they used a chemical to perform the test. Each `X_METER_USE` entry is associated with a project number stored in a column called `PROJECT`. The relationship here is one project can have many `X_METER_USE` entries associated with it. So the `PROJECT` column has duplicate entries corresponding to all the tests performed on that project.

Here is the table:

[image]

And here are some example entries

[image]

I need a query to find a few project numbers that the engineers have entered tests with both chemicals and instruments so I can test a front end web interface and make sure my logic there is correct. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `intersect` as simplest way to check what you want

```
select * from X_METER_USE 
where project in (
    SELECT x.project FROM X_METER_USE x
    INNER JOIN INSTRUMENTS i on x.ID_NUMBER = i.NAME 
    where x.INST_SNR = 'INSTRUMENT'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT x.project FROM X_METER_USE x
    INNER JOIN STANDARD_REAGENT sr ON x.ID_NUMBER = sr.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
    where x.INST_SNR = 'SNR'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find projects that have both chemical tests and instrument tests.

To do that, I believe you would do:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT FROM X_METER_USE WHERE INST_SNR = "INSTRUMENT") AS X
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT FROM X_METER_USE WHERE INST_SNR = "SNR") AS Y
ON X.PROJECT = Y.PROJECT
```

to get a table with a single field (project) containing those projects tested by both methods.  You can then join that to your projects table to get the full information about the project if necessary (though for just the numbers you don't even need that).  (You generally only want left or right joins when there's a possibility that an entry on one side doesn't have a match on the other, and you want those entries; here, you don't want untested projects or tests that don't have valid project entries, so you want an inner join.)

Comment: So your logic seems correct, however there is an error when I try to run the script I get a syntax error on the first "AS" in both oracle SQL developer and my datagrip IDE,